# jquery activating a specific node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

This is a seemlingly simple question, but I'm wracking my brain trying to figure this one out.

I have a JQuery accordion on my page.

I'm writing a client-side script to find a specific node based on a parameter passed through a querystring. This code finds me the specific node in the accordion:

```
$('.accordion').find('.nodeclass');
```

Question - how do I deactivate all the other nodes in the accordion and expand only the one passed through the querystring parameter?

Comment: Is it jQueryUI's accordion? If so, expanding one section should collapse the rest.

Comment: Yes, it's a JQueryUI accordion. I'm looking for the script to expand the node I've found in my sample script. (I find the node, but I've tried both toggle() and activate())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to close all the nodes of the accordion (i'm guessing here) you need and then open only one you must do

```
//close all
$('.accordion').accordion('activate', false);
//open one
$('.accordion').accordion('activate', idxofaccordion);
```

where `idxofaccordion` is the index (0 based) of the accordion you want to open. In the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) page look under "methods" for reference.

You could also try to select just one without clasing all the panels before, it might work

Comment: The nature of the accordion is to only have one section open at a time. I don't think the 'close all' call is necessary. Also, you can pass a selector to `activate` which might be more relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Figures after I post the question I wound up figuring it out...I can attach a click() handler and simulate a mouse click on the node.

Comment: you should use the API instead of simulatin a click